# Matplotlib pcolor

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using Matplotlib to create an image based on some data. All of the data falls in the range of 0 through to 1 and I am trying to color the data based on its value using a colormap and this works perfectly in Matlab, however when converting the code across to Python I simply get a black square as the output. I believe this is because I'm plotting the image wrong and so it is plotting all the data as 0. I have tried searching this problem for several hours and I have tried `plt.set_clim([0, 1])` however that didn't seem to do anything. I am new to Python and Matplotlib, although I am not new to programming (Java, javascript, PHP, etc), but I cannot see where I am going wrong. If any body can see anything glaringly incorrect in my code then I would be extremely grateful.

Thank you

```
from numpy import *
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as myColor

e1cx=[]
e1cy=[]
e1cz=[]
print("Reading files...")
in_file = open("eigenvector_1_component_x.txt", "rt")
for line in in_file.readlines():
e1cx.append([])
for i in line.split():
    e1cx[-1].append(float(i))
in_file.close()
in_file = open("eigenvector_1_component_y.txt", "rt")
for line in in_file.readlines():
e1cy.append([])
for i in line.split():
    e1cy[-1].append(float(i))
in_file.close()
in_file = open("eigenvector_1_component_z.txt", "rt")
for line in in_file.readlines():
e1cz.append([])
for i in line.split():
    e1cz[-1].append(float(i))
in_file.close()
print("...done")

nx = 120
ny = 128
nz = 190


fx = zeros((nz,nx,ny))
fy = zeros((nz,nx,ny))
fz = zeros((nz,nx,ny))

z = 0
while z<nz-1:
x = 0
while x<nx:
    y = 0
    while y<ny:
        fx[z][x][y]=e1cx[(z*128)+y][x]
        fy[z][x][y]=e1cy[(z*128)+y][x]
        fz[z][x][y]=e1cz[(z*128)+y][x]
        y += 1
    x += 1
z+=1
if((z % 10) == 0):      
    plt.figure(num=None)
    plt.axis("off")
    normals = myColor.Normalize(vmin=0,vmax=1)
    plt.pcolor(fx[z][:][:],cmap='spectral', norm=normals)   
    filename = 'Imagex_%d' % z
    plt.savefig(filename)
    plt.colorbar(ticks=[0,2,4,6], format='%0.2f')
```

Comment: Where is `e1cx`, `e1cy`, `e1cz` defined? Did you check whether you really have non-zero data?

Comment: sorry I shouldn't have chopped that bit out of my code, they are defined above now. Also I have checked and it is non-zero data. Thanks

Comment: Can you also post a few lines from the first file? And could you please check the indentation of your code. It is a bit off, and I don't want to guess what belongs where.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I've managed to resolve it by inserting the plotting into its own loop. It works perfectly now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although you have resolved your original issue and have code that works, I wanted to point out that both python and numpy provide several tools that make code like this much simpler to write. Here are a few examples:

### Loading data

Instead of building up lists by appending to the end of an empty one, it is often easier to generate them from other lists. For example, instead of

```
e1cx = []
for line in in_file.readlines():
  e1cx.append([])
  for i in line.split():
    e1cx[-1].append(float(i))
```

you can simply write:

```
e1cx = [[float(i) for i in line.split()] for line in in_file]
```

The syntax `[x(y) for y in l]` is known as a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), and, in addition to being more concise will execute more quickly than a `for` loop.

However, for loading tabular data from a text file, it is even simpler to use `numpy.loadtxt`:

```
import numpy as np
e1cx = np.loadtxt("eigenvector_1_component_x.txt")
```

for more information,

```
print np.loadtxt.__doc__
```

See also, its slightly more sophisticated cousin `numpy.genfromtxt`

### Reshaping data

Now that we have our data loaded, we need to reshape it. The while loops you use work fine, but `numpy` provides an easier way. First, if you prefer to use your method of loading the data, then convert your eigenvector arrays into proper numpy arrays using `e1cx = array(e1cx)`, etc.

The `array` class provides methods for rearranging how the data in an array is indexed without requiring it to be copied. The simplest method is `array.reshape`, which will do half of what your `while` loops do:

```
almost_fx = e1cx.reshape((nz,ny,nx))
```

Here, `almost_fx` is a rank-3 array indexed as `almost_fx[iz,iy,ix]`. One important thing to be aware of is that `e1cx` and `almost_fx` share their data. So, if you change `e1cx[0,0]`, you will also change `almost_fx[0,0,0]`.

In your code, you swapped the x and y locations. If this is indeed what you wanted to do, you can accomplish this with `array.swapaxes`:

```
fx = almost_fx.swapaxes(1,2)
```

Of course, you could always combine this into one line

```
fx = e1cx.reshape((nz,ny,nx)).swapaxes(1,2)
```

However, if you want the z-slices (`fx[z,:,:]`) to plot with x horizontal and y vertical, you probably do not want to swap the axes above. Just reshape and plot.

### Slicing arrays

Finally, rather than looping over the z-index and testing for multiples of 10, you can loop directly over a slice of the array using:

```
for fx_slice in fx[::10]:
  # plot fx_slice and save it
```

This indexing syntax is `array[start:end:step]` where `start` is included in the result `end` is not. Leaving `start` blank implies 0, while leaving `end` blank implies the end of the list.

### Summary

In summary your complete code (after introducing a few more python idioms like `enumerate`) could look something like:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as pt

shape = (190,128,120)

fx = np.loadtxt("eigenvectors_1_component_x.txt").reshape(shape).swapaxes(1,2)

for i,fx_slice in enumerate(fx[::10]):
  z = i*10
  pt.figure()
  pt.axis("off")
  pt.pcolor(fx_slice, cmap='spectral', vmin=0, vmax=1)
  pt.colorbar(ticks=[0,2,4,6], format='%0.2f')
  pt.savefig('Imagex_%d' % z)
```

Alternatively, if you want one pixel per element, you can replace the body of the `for` loop with

```
z = i*10
pt.imsave('Imagex_%d' % z, fx_slice, cmap='spectral', vmin=0, vmax=1)
```

Comment: this is brilliant. I am surprised that there are only 4 "ups".